mi problema con valor nulo
tengo un código en laravel 10 aprendiendo de a poco pero ahora mismo tengo este error "Attempt to read property "name" on null" y en mi base de datos tengo la información para que tenga que aparecer en mi view ayuda por favor no se cual puede ser mi error al hacer el código por lo que se yo al menos tengo todo bien en los llamados en la vista y para la creación de las relaciones en los modelos bien echa y me e estado comiendo la cabeza mucho se apreciaría cualquier ayuda
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\app.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>prueba</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tittle">
        <h1>hola</h1>
    </div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">id</th>
                <th scope="col">nombre</th>
                <th scope="col">correo</th>
                <th scope="col">ciudad</th>
                <th scope="col">pais</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->city->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->city && $user->city->country ? $user->city->country->name : 'N/A'}}</td>
            </tr> 
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>

los modelos que estoy usando
```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Country;

class City extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function User()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }

    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(country::class);
    }
}
```
```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\City;

class Country extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function city()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(city::class);
    }
}
```

```

?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use App\Models\City;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
    ];

    public function city(){
        return $this->belongsTo(city::class);
    }
}
```


está media vacía la publicacion pero yendo en que el problema está en las relaciones:
En la línea que dice {{$user->city->name}}, estás asumiendo que cada usuario tiene una relación city definida en su modelo y que esta relación también tiene una propiedad name para mostrar el nombre de la ciudad. Esto podría causar un error si un usuario no tiene una ciudad asociada.
Podes evitarlo y ver si es por eso, así:
{{ $user->city ? $user->city->name : 'N/A' }}


muy pocas veces pregunto por aquí y en si los usuarios que tengo en la base de datos tiene una ciudad asociada lo mismo con las ciudades y los países

ojo que estás llamando a las clases con minuscula en las relaciones
